# Variables in a custom plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, plist

I know it's possible to store variables in the default Info.plist file by preprocessing the Info.plist file.  I'm wondering if it's possible to do something similar with a custom plist file.

I load the plist file via the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *customPlistPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"custom.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:customPlistPath];
```

Is it possible to put in values like ${PRODUCT_NAME} or ${MY_OWN_VARIABLE_NAME} and have them honored in the custom plist file after I read it in?  Currently, the variable values aren't being substituted when I read the custom plist file into an NSDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into the Cocoa Touch framework that will do this for you. You have to write your own code to process the values at runtime. I've done this for my own app. I used these two methods in a utility class.

```
+ (NSString *)processVariables:(NSString *)string {
    if (string.length == 0) {
        return string;
    }

    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"${" options:NSLiteralSearch];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSMutableString *res = [string mutableCopy];
        do {
            NSRange close = [res rangeOfString:@"}" options:NSLiteralSearch];
            if (close.location == NSNotFound) {
                break; // Uh-oh - bad
            }

            NSRange rngVar = NSMakeRange(range.location, close.location - range.location + 1);
            NSString *var = [res substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(rngVar.location + 2, rngVar.length - 3)];
            NSString *val = [variables objectForKey:var];
            if (val) {
                [res replaceCharactersInRange:rngVar withString:val];
            } else {
                [res replaceCharactersInRange:rngVar withString:var];
            }

            range = [res rangeOfString:@"${" options:NSLiteralSearch];
        } while (range.location != NSNotFound);

        return res;
    } else {
        return string;
    }
}

+ (id)expandPlistVariables:(id)root {
    if ([root isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSArray *array = (NSArray *)root;
        NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:array.count];
        for (id obj in array) {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                [res addObject:[self processVariables:(NSString *)obj]];
            } else {
                id newObj = [self expandPlistVariables:obj];
                [res addObject:newObj];
            }
        }

        return res;
    } else if ([root isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)root;
        NSMutableDictionary *res = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:dict.count];
        for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
            id obj = dict[key];
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                res[key] = [self processVariables:(NSString *)obj];
            } else {
                id newObj = [self expandPlistVariables:obj];
                res[key] = newObj;
            }
        }

        return res;
    } else {
        // oops
        return root;
    }
}
```

You would pass in your dictionary (or array) loaded from a plist and get back a new dictionary (or array) where all string values that contained variable references have been updated.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *customPlistPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"custom.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:customPlistPath];
plistData = [UtilityClass expandPlistVariables:plistData];
```

In the code, `variables` is an `NSDictionary` containing the variable values. The keys in this dictionary are the values in your plist between the `${` and `}`. Example:

```
variables = @{ @"PRODUCT_NAME" : @"MyProduct", @"MY_OWN_VARIABLE_NAME" : @"Some Value" };
```

Comment: the function "processVariables" returns a string. Are you sure you want to call : plistData = [UtilityClass processVariables:plistData]; ? Where plistData is a NSDictionary

Comment: If you modify your answer so that `plistData = [UtilityClass expandPlistVariables:plistData];` instead of **process_Variables**, I will gladly accept your answer as it works beautifully! Thank you thank you thank you :)

Comment: Oops - that was a typo. Thanks for fixing. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could use your solution in a non-arc project? Meaning, what exactly would I need to release? THank you again

Comment: That should be easy enough to figure out. Release anything that you own. If you call `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, or `retain` then you must call `release` or `autorelease` on the object.